# How to assign MS Windows drive letter to a formatted partition?

Tags: format

I have formatted one of my partitions from Ubuntu as ntfs, and now when I try to restore my windows OS to that partition, the restore utility (which resides in the first partition, fails saying that it was unable to locate "C:" drive.

Is there a way in Ubuntu to assign the drive letter to a partition when I format it as ntfs?

Comment: What kind of a restore utility are you using? Is it something from Ubuntu? Otherwise, you'd be better of asking somewhere else.

Comment: I am talking about my laptop, which came pre-installed with Windows Vista. The first partition is the restoration partition, when I boot through it, it allows me to reinstall Windows

Comment: Well the restore utility will wipe out the drive and fill it with Windows, as is manufacturer specs.  The main reason you may not have "C:" anymore is because you formatted the windows partition.  You'll need to reinstall windows, and then install Ubuntu.  However, ***DO NOT "FORMAT" THE NTFS PARTITION!*** Just resize it next time.

Comment: I think the restoration partition of Windows can restore a broken system not a "no system" newly formatted partition (it can't be used to install a system since it's not complete
). Am I wrong?

Comment: Well, there are a few hiccups. My DVD drive doesn't works. The only way for me to install windows is via USB drive or if I can somehow label the partition as C: so that the restoration utility can continue with the partition.

Answer (score 1):

No there isnt.  There's no way to assign a Windows drive letter to a partition from Ubuntu.  You'd have to run a Windows installation CD to repair the install of Windows.

Comment: @Takkat The C: letter is assigned only when the system gets installed.  It cannot be reassigned later.  That means that if the C: partition is no longer detected, then the system needs repaired (not reinstalled, repaired).  To do that you need a Windows Install CD.

Comment: There is no rule, how Windows assigns drive letters to partitions. The system partition is typically (always) assigned "C:". Other partitions are labeleld in the order of appearance, typically this is correlated to the partition layout. If you install Windows twice on the same computer, they will have different letters for the same partition. Modern Windows versions remember, which letter they assigned to which partition, and the letter can be changed via disk manager.

Comment: But only from within Windows, @Jan.  They are asking for an ***UBUNTU*** way of setting the drive letter.  Such a method does not exist.